# Half-reverse a binary string

Tags: code-golf, string

This is a follow-up question to my [Puzzling.SE question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28363/half-reverse-operation-on-binary-strings): I asked if there’s a function **f** mapping Boolean strings to Boolean strings, so that **f(f(b)) = reverse(b)** for all input strings **b**. (By **reverse**, I mean the function that reverses the order of bits.)

The above link contains a positive answer, with proof, by the great *f''*, but you might want to ponder the question for yourself before looking.

Implement such a function **f** in as few bytes as possible.

- You may either read input from STDIN, or take a function argument; and either write the result string to STDOUT, or return it.
- Either way, you may work with actual strings of two distinct bytes or characters of your choice (say `0` and `1`, or `\x00` and `\x01`), or with arrays/lists of [truthy and falsy values](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey). Pick two values and stick with those, though.
- The result of a single application of **f** *must* be a binary string itself: no silly answers like `b -> if b starts with 'x' then reverse(b[1:]) else 'x' + b`...
- Your function should be *total*; in particular, the input may be the empty string, or one bit long, etc. There’s no upper bound for the string’s length.
- It should also be *pure*: don’t keep any global state between function calls; the input string must completely determine the output string.

Comment: Can output have different length than input?

Comment: Sure! (In fact, otherwise, the challenge is provably impossible.)

Comment: Does it have to work for strings of length one or zero?

Comment: Yes; the function has to be total. I’ve clarified this in the question!

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11969/8478)

Comment: This would have been much easier if you wanted to half-flip a binary string i.e. `f(f(b))=map(~,b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CJam, 32 bytes

```
1q1]s:~__W%.&_,2/0t0#2%{2>W%2>}|
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1q1%5Ds%3A%7E__W%25.%26_%2C2%2F0t0%232%25%7B2%3EW%252%3E%7D%7C)

Too long...

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 64 <s>69</s> bytes

```py
def f(s):p=(s+s).find(s,1);return[s[~p::-1],s+s[:p]][len(s)/p%2]
```

Ungolfed:

```py
def f(s):
    p = (s+s).find(s,1)
    n = len(s)/p
    return s[:p][::1|n%-2] * -~(n-1^1)
```

This finds the string's period, i.e. the minimal `p` such that `s` is a string of length `p` repeated `n` times (I found a [golfy method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489919) on SO). Then if `n` is odd, it adds one more repetition of the period. If `n` is even, it removes one repeat of the period and reverses it.

<s>Thanks to @Sp3000 for helping to implement the function mapping between 1<->2, 3<->4, etc.</s>

Comment: ...When will the ungolfed code be updated?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I have no plan to modify the ungolfed code as it uses the same idea with only a trivial difference. The English on the other hand is up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>49</s> 47 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Based on @feersum's very nice algorithm

Run with input on STDIN, e.g.

```
perl -lp halfreverse.pl <<< "101001"
```

`halfreverse.pl`:

```
/^(.+?)((\1\1?)*)$/;$_=$3eq$1?reverse$2:$_.$1
```

### Explanation

```
/^               $/         Match the complete input string
  (.+?)                     Non-greedy match. Try only one digit at the start,
                            if that doesn't work try 2, then 3 etc. The string
                            being tried is remembered in backreference \1
       ((\1\1?)*)           Try to repeat \1 as many times as possible but
                            prefer in groups of 2. Fall back to only 1 at the
                            end of the string if the trailing part has an odd
                            number of \1 (so the total count is even)

   $3eq$1                   So the last match $3 equals the first match $1
         ?                  if and only if the total count is even
          reverse$2         If total count is even drop the first instance of
                   :        \1 and reverse
                    $_.$1   If total count is odd extend $_ by one instance
$_=                         Assign result
```

Comment: How does it work??